# Meaning of 4th column in output of ls -l

Tags: command-line, ls

In 2nd line here I see *'u001'* then *'root'*, 1st is owner as I understand, but what is 2nd ?

```
drwx------ 13 u001 u001     4096 jun 21 03:29 .cache
drwxr-xr-x 18 u001 root     4096 jun 21 03:30 .config
drwxr-xr-x  2 u001 u001     4096 jun 21 02:54 Desktop
```

How could I change it to u001 ?

Comment: Group ownership. Please read the manual. It's all there

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy how could I change group ?

Comment: Since that is a directory the command of `sudo chown -R u001:u001 .config/` should change that folder and all of it contents to the proper ownership.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership  Chances are an application that writes into the `~/.config` folder was ran as `sudo` causing it to change the group owner.

Comment: Look at the answer to this question: [How do I change directory to get into a hidden folder/directory?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040437/29012).  It expands on what Terrance presented to you in his link.